# Visual Studio 2015 breaks EPPlus Colors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, epplus

Spent hours fussing with this until I narrowed it down to VS 2015. This worked just fine in VS 2013:

```
myWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
```

But in VS 2015, though it compiles just fine, when I run the solution it throws an exception:

> Color.LightGray = {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.AddEventHandler(Object key, Delegate value
>   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.add_UserPreferenceChanging(UserPreferenceChangingEventH...

Is there another way to specify color that will work?

Comment: No.  You will have to post code that shows how the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanging event could possibly be relevant.  It is a very notorious event for sure, bytes back hard when you create UI on a worker thread.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you suggest I post code that shows how the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanging event would be relevant. Refer to Stewart's code snippet below. That's all there is. If I create a new console solution and add only that code I still get the null reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with VS 2015. If I do this:

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1");
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "light grey";
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

    excel.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\temp\temp.xlsx"));
}
```

then I get the expected output:

[image]

A couple of possible reasons this could throw an exception:

- Have you first set the Fill's `.PatternType` property to `ExcelFillStyle.Solid` ?
- Do you have a reference to System.Drawing for the correct target framework? (That this happened after a VS upgrade makes me wonder if your references are targetting .NET 4.5 but your project targetting a later version?).

Comment: This is a new solution I created with VS 2015 . Only the syntax is a copy and paste from a similar project, There's only one version of System.Drawing listed in the framework (4.5.2) and that is version 4.0.30319.34211. Maybe if I point to .NET 4.5.0?

Comment: I updated all the projects in the solution to point to .NET 4.5 and confirmed with Assembly Explorer at I'm referencing the same System.Drawing version. Still getting the exception.

Comment: Just for chuckles and grins I copied your code verbatim but without the System.Drawing reference. Red squigly hint was that I needed to add a reference to System.Drawing 2.0 but when a let it automagically add the reference for me it added 4.0. I get the same null reference exception when I run the project.

Comment: Last note for tonight. I created a console application with VS 2013, added references to EPPlus and System.Drawing and ran the solution. Worked just fine. Then I opened the solution with VS 2015 and tried to run it and it threw the null reference exception at: 

ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

Comment: How odd. Can you zip up the solution (maybe even invlude the bin files) where you did everything from scratch and post it someplace? I'll download and run it to determine if it's the solution or your environment.

Comment: Only thing I hate more than this kind of mystery is this kind of mystery that resolves after I ask for help. Restarted PC and ran your sample and it worked. Thanks Stewart.